# limiting date with quasar v1

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using quasar date component with limiting dates.
The documentation says to use `options` prop to be supplied with an array or function.

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <div class="q-gutter-md">
      <q-date
        v-model="date"
        :options="options"
      />

      <q-date
        v-model="date"
        :options="optionsFn"
      />

      <q-date
        v-model="date"
        :options="optionsFn2"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      date: '2019/02/01',
      options: [ '2019/02/01', '2019/02/05', '2019/02/06', '2019/02/09', '2019/02/23' ]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    optionsFn (date) {
      return date >= '2019/02/03' && date <= '2019/02/15'
    },

    optionsFn2 (date) {
      const parts = date.split('/')
      return parts[2] % 2 === 0
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that I am not able to pass any other argument in the `optionsFn` function.

Comment: What happens if you pass?

Comment: @TachibanaShin I dont recieve `date` in the function argument. I have tried using `$event` and `...arguments` as well.

Comment: you are using quasar 1.x correct?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: i tried and it still works please reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/rstoenescu/rmaodk0f

Comment: Please have a look https://jsfiddle.net/ufhpy2sg

Comment: It is not possible to pass other arguments to that function - but you can pass different functions to different `<q-date>` components. And your last fiddle does not work. You must change it like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/se91g3at/)

Comment: since `options` takes in a function call but you are passing `options=` the return result of that function is not allowed you can fix it to `:options="date => optionsFn(date, 'test ')"` and it will work as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `options` takes in a function call but you are passing `options=` the return result of that function is not allowed you can fix it to `:options="date => optionsFn(date, 'test ')"` and it will work as you want